# I'm trying to use the after function to run code alongside Tkinter GUI and am running into problems

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My eventual goal is to take user input from the Python shell and based on this input change things about the GUI. My current code was a sort of test of concept to understand how to use the after function, and for some reason I can't get it to run properly. The function runs properly, but if i try to resize the GUI it freezes and crashes. I'm running this script on Windows (a friend is running on linux and works fine as is, but I suck at linux and would like to stay in windows if possible). Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated!!

```html
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def ok():
    
    test=input()
    if(test=='left'):
        print('yup')
    root.after(100,ok)
    
    
root=Tk()
    
frame=Frame(root)
root.title("Phrase Generator")
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,1, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,2, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,3, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,4, weight=1)
grid=Frame(frame)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton",foreground="black", font="Times 20 bold")
ttk.Style().theme_use('vista')



b1=ttk.Button(root, text="1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
b2=ttk.Button(root, text="2").grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
b3=ttk.Button(root, text="3").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
b4=ttk.Button(root, text="4").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
b5=ttk.Button(root, text="ON").grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=N+S+E+W)


root.after(100, ok)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try QT designer... much easier in use.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Are you getting an error? The freeze is understandable, since the GUI is waiting for a response from stdin. It won't refresh until you enter something.

Comment: The `input()` inside `ok()` will block the tkinter `mainloop()`.  Try using thread instead of `after()`.